# Get JSON depending on the execution environment

Tags: c#

ASP.NET Core has a Configuration property injected, and I can use it to access to appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json… depending on the execution environment.

The problem is I am in another project outside the API and I want the same functionality.

I am doing tests with a console project, but I can't access to the environment.

```
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"); // ?????
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(path)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
    .Build();

Console.WriteLine(builder.GetConnectionString("Database"));
```

Comment: An environment variable and an execution environment are not the same thing, they are related, but I think you may have some confusion

Comment: @maccettura No. I want know the execution environment, and the approach I have seen is using a environment variable.

Comment: Well you dont even use `environment` in your code after the first line.  Its not really clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @maccettura I am trying to access to a different JSON file depending on the execution environment (production: appsettings.json, development: appsettings.Development.json, staging: appsettings.Staging.json).

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for config transforms, [here](https://dzone.com/articles/config-transformations-in-aspnet-core-1) is a quick intro to it.  I think you are close, you just need to rename the files and add the setting in the right place

Comment: @maccettura There is a problem: There is no launchSettings.json outside the ASP.NET Core project

Comment: Ok, well how do you expect to access a json file that does not exist on your machine?

Comment: @maccettura Ok. I have created launchSettings.json, but how can I receive the environment depending the execution environment? I have the profile "ConsoleApp1" (the name of the project) with "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development". I don't want to manually change the string

Comment: I still honestly have no idea what you are asking.  I dont want my confusing to lead to any miscommunication so I am going to let someone else try to take a swing at this